# How to convert a integral into the another?

Tags: calculus, number-theory

There is a function here: http://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/PrimePi/21/01/01/0001/

How to convert it into the answer for indefinite integral $\int \pi(x) dx$ where pi(x) stand for prime counting function.

Comment: $\int \pi(x) dx$ diverges.

Comment: what does that mean? @MustafaSaid

Comment: I guess you are looking at the indefinite integral, my bad.

Comment: Are you looking for a derivation of this equality? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @RyanMcGaha - No, but i hope that link help to evaluate the integral

Comment: @Victor An excellent explanation is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U16_KTTKtb0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this may not be the answer you're looking for but it's probably too long for a comment. I'm unsure if there is an explicit solution to the indefinite integral but we can find a solution if the integral is from 0 to infinity because $\pi (x)$=$O$($x\over ln(x)$).
Therefore using this expression, you can find a solution to this definite integral but as MustafaSaid said this integral diverges and so its value is $\infty$. But for the indefinite integral I'm unsure if it has a solution.